# How to deal with InstanceLimitExceeded for EC2 instances?

Tags: amazon-ec2, vagrant, cloud, vagrantfile, quota

I'm using vagrant to run multiple AWS EC2 instances in parallel, however I've hit the [default limit](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/faqs/#How_many_instances_can_I_run_in_Amazon_EC2) of 20 instances per region (`t2.small` in `us-east-1`):

> There was an error talking to AWS.
>
> InstanceLimitExceeded => Your quota allows for 0 more running instance(s). You requested at least 1

Reading [troubleshooting page](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/auto-scaling-troubleshooting/), it's suggested that I should contact AWS support and [create a case](https://console.aws.amazon.com/support/home#/case/create?issueType=service-limit-increase) to ask for a higher limit (which I did and I'm waiting for the response).

> EC2 Service Limits: AWS sets limits for these resources on a per-region basis.

However **is there any other workaround for such limitation** in terms of scaling?

In other words, if there is a limit per region, **is there any way of dynamically assign a different region** or type of instance to workaround the limitation?

---

I'm using `vagrant-aws` vagrant plugin with the following AWS settings in my [`Vagrantfile`](https://github.com/EA31337/FX-MT-VM/blob/0ef7e1b9c56779d26c87fac654057154debdae1e/Vagrantfile):

```
config.vm.provider :aws do |aws, override|
    aws.ami = "ami-fce3c696"
    aws.instance_type = "t2.small"
    aws.keypair_name = keypair_name
    aws.region = "us-east-1"
    aws.terminate_on_shutdown = true
    if private_key then override.ssh.private_key_path = private_key end
    if security_group then aws.security_groups = [ security_group ] end
    if subnet_id then aws.subnet_id = subnet_id end
    override.nfs.functional = false
    override.ssh.username = "ubuntu"
    override.vm.box = "my_test"
    override.vm.box_url = "https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant-aws/raw/master/dummy.box"
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you cannot "borrow" from limits in other regions.  You could create another account, but then you'd have to deal with the additional administrative overhead of enabling shared access of resources across the accounts.  Also note the limits are per instance type.  You could try using a different instance type.

In the future, since the turnaround for limit increases can be a couple days, and varies by type of limit increase, be sure to plan ahead.  Especially for lower-tier support contracts, they do not consider limit increase requests to be emergencies.

Answer (score 1):

As [@Karen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38034808/55075) already mentioned, the limit is per instance type, so as for workaround, 20 instances can be run for t2.nano, t2.micro, t2.small, etc.

Here is the code in `Vagrantfile` which can load the instance type as a parameter:

```
require 'getoptlong'

# Parse CLI arguments.
opts = GetoptLong.new(
  [ '--instance-type',  GetoptLong::OPTIONAL_ARGUMENT ],
)

instance_type  = ENV['INSTANCE_TYPE'] || 't2.small'
begin
  opts.each do |opt, arg|
    case opt
      when '--instance-type';  instance_type  = arg
    end # case
  end # each
  rescue
end

Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
  # ...
  config.vm.provider :aws do |aws, override|
    aws.instance_type = instance_type
#   ...
  end
end
```

Then you can run as:

```
INSTANCE_TYPE=t2.nano vagrant up
INSTANCE_TYPE=t2.micro vagrant up
INSTANCE_TYPE=t2.small vagrant up
INSTANCE_TYPE=t2.medium vagrant up
INSTANCE_TYPE=t2.large vagrant up
```

and so on. So having 5 different instances, the limit may reach 100 instances to run simultaneously.